# Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set: Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics has exited with Exit code: -3

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

When deploying an ARM template to create a Virtual Machine Scale Set, the installation of the final, azure diagnostics extension fails.

`Handler 'Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics' has reported failure for VM Extension 'VMDiagnostics_Name' with terminal error code '1009' and error message: 'Enable failed for plugin (name: Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics, version 1.7.4.0) with exception Command C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics\1.7.4.0\DiagnosticsPluginLauncher.exe of Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics has exited with Exit code: -3'`

Can't see what caused the problem when remote desktop connected to one of the servers.

From the ARM Template (standard):

```
"extensionProfile": {
    "extensions": [ (...)
{
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics",
        "type": "IaaSDiagnostics",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.5",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
            "WadCfg": {
                "DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
                    "overallQuotaInMB": "50000",
                    "EtwProviders": {
                        "EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration": [
                            {
                                "provider": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Actors",
                                "scheduledTransferKeywordFilter": "1",
                                "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
                                "DefaultEvents": {
                                    "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableActorEventTable"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "provider": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Services",
                                "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
                                "DefaultEvents": {
                                    "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableServiceEventTable"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "EtwManifestProviderConfiguration": [
                            {
                                "provider": "cbd93bc2-71e5-4566-b3a7-595d8eeca6e8",
                                "scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter": "Information",
                                "scheduledTransferKeywordFilter": "4611686018427387904",
                                "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
                                "DefaultEvents": {
                                    "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricSystemEventTable"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "StorageAccount": "storageaccountname"
        }
    },
    "name": "VMDiagnostics_Name"
}
```

Anyone know what's breaking this deployment?

Comment: Got the same issue and exit code.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on one of my clusters VMSS.  I have yet to solve it but I dug into one of the VMs and checked the Windows logs and the exit is due to a missing cert thumbprint in the runtime settings file:
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics\1.7.4.0\RuntimeSettings
In a working VMSS configuration the settings file has:

```
{
  "runtimeSettings": [
    {
      "handlerSettings": {
        "protectedSettingsCertThumbprint": "7F7682DBF9CB9C4D8F6768602973A49CC16D2523"
```

where the thumbprint is the "TenantEncryptionCert". The VMSS with the failure has an equivalent cert but the settings file is missing the thumbprint entry.  I removed the extension and then attempted a redeploy but the same result.

Comment: This is possibly what was causing my issue too. I did have some certificate issues. In the end, I gave up trying to redeploy the template I exported from an existing instance, and recreated a template using the service fabric "create" from the marketplace. Then just edited back in what I needed.